# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC on Excel Interop v2.0.50727 and VS2017

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2017, excel-interop

I've already try solutions found on StackOverflow and Google without results so I ask you:

(I know it could be written in one instruction but I need to find the error)
I have this code:

```
            var excelAppInput = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelAppInput.Visible = true;
            Workbook wbInput = excelAppInput.Workbooks.Open(textBoxFileOriginale.Text);
            Worksheet wsInput = (Worksheet)wbInput.Sheets[1];

            Worksheet ws = null;
            ws = (Worksheet)wbInput.Worksheets.Add(After: wsInput);
            ws.Name = "Destinazione";
            wsInput.Activate();

            Range rigaInput;
            Range rigaOutput;

            for (int riga = 2; riga <= rowCount; riga++)
            {
                Range c1 = wsInput.Cells[riga, 1];
                Range c2 = wsInput.Cells[riga, colCount];
                rigaInput = ws.Range[c1,c2];
                rigaInput.Copy(ws.Cells[rigaDest,1]);
                rigaDest++;
            }
```

I always have on:
rigaInput = ws.Range[c1,  c2]
"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

NOTE: rigaDest, colCount and rowCount are set before in the code.

Comment: `rigaInput = ws.Range[c1,c2];` should be `rigaInput = wsInput.Range[c1,c2];` -- change `ws` to `wsInput`

Comment: Too many hours awake coding take me to this silly mistakes, thanks.